# Is a movie played in a theater or at a theater?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Do we say a movie is being played *in* a theater or *at* a theater?

Comment: In the UK, a film is "on at the cinema".

Comment: Of late it's more likely to be seen in a *theatre*.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, the verb *play* is usually active with regard to movies, rather than passive.

> - *The movie is playing at the Bijou.*
> - *The movie plays in local theaters before going to DVD.*

Both prepositional forms, *at* and *in* are regularly found, but *in* is more common with the generic term *theater* and *at* with the specific theater name.

With the verb *show*, the passive form is found, and *in* is more common.

> *The movie is being shown in a theater*.

With truncated forms, either preposition can be used:

> - *Now in a theater near you!*
> - *Now at a theater near you!*

Answer (score 0):

In the US, the phrase is "at the theater", and it's usually more specific than that -- "Die Hard 26 is playing at the Googleplex theater." The phrase "in a theater" would only be used if there was a question as to whether it was being played in the usual situation or outside, at someone's house, or in some other location.

Answer (score 0):

"at" is normally used if you're stating a specific place like "at the top of the closet", or "at the Central Plaza" and "in' is used if you're not stating a specific place like "we'll meet in China next month". it is specifically stated that the place will be in China but not where exactly in China. ;)
(if I stated something wrong, please let me know)

Answer (score 0):

"In" is used when talking about a closed space where someone physically is. For example: 'I am in the theater' means that I am physically in the building. 'At' is used more as a general meaning. 'I am at the theater' would refer more to the concept, like I went to see a movie, and not that I am in that exact location.

Other examples:

- I am in the office. (in the physical space)
- I am at the office. (I am working, I am somewhere in my workplace)

Exception of this are geographical names, we always use "in" with countries, cities, etc.

But even here, sometimes we see this same rule:
I am at the lake (somewhere close to the lake, the exact location is not important) or
I am in the lake (I am physically in the water).